# Thread Safety - background thread and cache => avoid race conditions

Tags: android, multithreading, thread-safety

I want to keep my background threads and my views completely seperated, therefore I use threads and a bus system (actually I use a job manager, the one from here: https://github.com/path/android-priority-jobqueue). For a better user experience, I cache already calculated or loaded data in a `LruCache`. I've written a wrapper for making it thread safe. Every work that has to be done in the background is identified by a tag.

I keep track of working threads in an own singleton class.

My threads work like following:

- put the tag of the work into a list in a singleton class => meaning, work will be done
- do work
- save result in cache
- post an event to the bus
- remove tag from the list of the singleton class => meaning, work has been done

I use this system like following, when a fragment is resumed:

- register on bus
- check cache for an existing result
- use cached data or check if a thread is calculating the desired data by checking the tag in the singleton class's list
- if a thread is working on the desired data, wait for it, otherwise, start a new thread

I think, this is prone to one race conditions:

- Thread finishes and posts it result to the bus
- => fragment is not registered yet because it's not resumed
- => Event will not be delivered but cached only
- => fragment get's resumed
- => fragment asks Status of work and sees that a thread is working on the desired data and does not start a new thread
- => thread clears the working state for the desired data

=> fragment will not receive it's data

How can I solve that problem? If I consider two independent threads, this race condition is possible. On andoroid, the thread will post on the main thread ALWAYS, does this effect my problem? I'm not sure about that actually...

Here's my main thread otto bus for completeness:

```
// defined in my application
private static final MainThreadBus BUS = new MainThreadBus(new Bus(ThreadEnforcer.ANY));

// the bus class
public class MainThreadBus extends Bus
{
private final Bus mBus;
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

public MainThreadBus(final Bus bus)
{
    if (bus == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("ERROR: bus == null");
    mBus = bus;
}

@Override
public void register(Object obj)
{
    mBus.register(obj);
}

@Override
public void unregister(Object obj)
{
    mBus.unregister(obj);
}

@Override
public void post(final Object event)
{
    if (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper())
    {
        mBus.post(event);
    }
    else
    {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                mBus.post(event);
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Otto's Producers might help you to delivery the already posted event when the fragment registers. Avoiding the no ones listening dispatch of an event.

Comment: for my use case, I produce the event manually, because I have events that are of the same type and include a page number... Consider a fragment that shows pages of unknown count... I can't create different events for every page as the page count is unknown...

Comment: You can synchronize your state changes (last 3 items on the first list) and read (all items on the second list) on a singleton monitor to provide atomicity and thread-safety. Also, you don't need to use a `Handler` for posting on the main thread, as Otto's event bus takes care of that by default.

Comment: Actually, I have to use a handler... I want to post from all threads and I use a `Bus(ThreadEnforcer.ANY)` therefore. This will lead to errors without the handler, that a thread that did not create a view can't change it... Therefore, I need the main thread bus...

Comment: You're right, I've to synchronize the blocks with a common lock object, I will do that... Actually, synchronizing the last 3 of the for list entries of the second list would do it as well, wouldn't it? I don't really know what you mean with a singleton monitor... Google does give results for thread safe singletons which I'm anyway using...

Comment: By synchronizing on a singleton monitor, I mean a common lock object, which should probably (but not necessarily) be a singleton (possibly one of those that you're already using). You can probably leave registering on the bus unsynchronized, but any conditional logic that deals with other threads depending on the state should be inside one synchronized block for atomicity. Both reads and writes on the cache should be included in the synchronized blocks.

Comment: Also the thread enforcement mechanism in Otto is not about enforcing the posting thread, but the callback thread. If you want to have all your callbacks delivered in the main thread, then you should use the default `ThreadEnforcer.MAIN`.

Comment: Thanks... I've implemented it like that now anyway... And I'll check that information about otto...

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong about `ThreadEnforcer` handling posting to a thread. The document was misleading, but actually it only enforces the posting thread. Your approach of using `Handler` was correct.

Comment: It really sounds like using @Produce method returning last good event would be the simplest solution.